# My Responsive Navbar toggle doesn't work (javascript)

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, addeventlistener, nav

I am trying to make a responsive navbar for my project (I am still a newbie learning this). I want to get a dropdown-like nav anchors when I click on the menu bar (3 horizontally parallel lines). I used the Eventlistener and it is not setting that toggle_button to 'active'. I have been going through YouTube videos, some questions on here, and references all over the internet and I cannot seem to find the solution.

Here is my code block.

---

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle_btn')[0];
 const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar_links')[0];

 toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
 });
```

```css
/*General Styling*/
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #d4af37 ;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 90vh;
    background: url("images/background.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", "serif";
  }

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px 100px;
}


a{
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
nav li {
    list-style: none;
}
nav li a {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: block;
}


/*Styling using class*/
.nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d4af37;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -6px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #d4af37;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .5s;
}

.nav:hover::after{
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

/*responsive button*/
.toggle_btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.5rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.toggle_btn .bar{
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a1852b;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


/*responsive nav bar*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .toggle_btn{
        display: flex;
    }
    .navbar_links{
  display:none;
  }
  
  header{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    nav ul{
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;

    }

    nav li{
        padding-left: 4rem;
    }

    nav li a{
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    nav.active {
        display: flex;
    }
  nav.active .nav{
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!--Logo and Nav-->
    <header> 
            <!--Logo and brandName-->
            <div id="logo_div"> 
                <img class="images" id="logo" src="images/logo+name.png" alt="Crux Logo and Brand Name here.">
            </div>
                <!--Nav bar-->
            <div id="nav_div">
                
                <!--Nav-bar toggle-->
                <a href="#" class="toggle_btn"> 
                    <span class="bar"> </span>
                    <span class="bar"> </span>
                    <span class="bar"> </span>
                </a>

                <nav class="navbar_links">
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a class="nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Try using a <button> instead of an <a> element, and giving the button an onclick function. That way you won't need the event handler. Also, I'd recommend to give the navbar an id, so that you can use document.getElementById instead of getElementByClass

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Well noted for the upcoming pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hamburger menu has a class of `toggle_btn`, but your JS is looking for elements with class of `toggle_button`, which don't exist, so your event listener is not being attached to anything.

Comment: And then after that, you also need to remove the `display: none` from your `.nav` selector, so that your links are actually visible within the hamburger dropdown.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have changed it and realised that I wrote the code for this under some other javascript EventLister code lines. I also needed to reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the wrong selector of the toggle button. It should be `toggle_btn` like in your HTML file instead of `toggle_button` in your JS file. Please check it again.

Comment: I was really sleepy at that time and overlooked it. Thank you for pointing it out!